# d3 + leaflet data bind breaks resampling

Tags: d3.js

So I've encountered a weird issue that I cannot for the life of me figure out. I think I know what's going on, but I could be wrong.

Typically when building a chloreopath map using d3, I load in my geojson and build the paths. I then call a second function to attach external data to the paths and color them accordingly.

That works fine for regular shapes (states, nations).

However, for irregular states (congressional districts), loading a basemap to orient users is ideal.

So I've been playing with Bostock's [d3 + leaflet example here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/).

Here's the code:

```
var map = new L.Map("map", {center: [40.037875, -76.305514], zoom: 8})
.addLayer(new L.TileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"));

var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");   

    d3.json("https://s3.amazonaws.com/WorkMalawskey/1test_map/state_house.json", function(json) {


    var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint}),
        path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

    var feature = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr('class', 'district');

map.on("viewreset", reset, color);
                    reset();
                    color();    


function reset() {

console.log('start reset');

var bounds = path.bounds(json),
    topLeft = bounds[0],
    bottomRight = bounds[1];

svg .attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
    .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
    .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
    .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

g.attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");

feature.attr("d", path).attr('class', 'district');

console.log('end reset');

};

function color() {

d3.csv("https://s3.amazonaws.com/WorkMalawskey/1test_map/house.csv", function(data) {

console.log('dataloaded');


d3.selectAll('.district')
.data(data)
.enter();

console.log('dataloaded2');

var Color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(['R', 'D'])
            .range(["#de2d26", "#3182bd"]); 

var Color2 = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(['No', 'Yes'])
            .range([0.5, 0.75]);    

d3.selectAll('.district').style('fill', function (d) { return Color(d.Party)}).style('opacity', function (d) { return Color2(d.Contested)});


}); 
}; 




function projectPoint(x, y) {
var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);

};  
});
```

My issue appears when I call the reset function, and subsequently call the color function. It would appear that the databinding is breaking, or interrupting, the path re-draw.

The reset function works fine, as long as the databind is not called. The color function works fine as well on initial load. It's when the two mix that things seem to break.

I'm also hungover, which probably contributes to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are binding **different datasets to the path at different times**.

**1st binding done here:**

```
   var feature = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)//all path will have feature bound to it.
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr('class', 'district');
```

**2nd Binding done here (setting the color properties)**

```
d3.selectAll('.district')
.data(data)
.enter();
```

So when you zoom in our out the path properties are lost because path doesn't have the feature data bound to it any more.

You should be doing like this (on loading the second set of json data for coloring and setting opacity):

```
  d3.selectAll('.district')[0].forEach(function(d, i){
    //to the current data add a new property to store the color information.
    d3.select(d).data()[0].colorProps = data[i];       
  });
```

Now your fill/opacity reset style property will look like this:

```
  d3.selectAll('.district').style('fill', function(d) {
    //as this property is now stored in colorProps
    return Color(d.colorProps.Party)
  }).style('opacity', function(d) {
    return Color2(d.colorProps.Contested)
  });
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hgNVOkTy6VfM0oJSN2yG?p=preview)

Comment: Oh God dammit. Duh, that makes perfect sense. 

I guess I've never double-binded data to an object and tried to access the original data before. But yeah, okay.

Thank you sir!